# Are there easy way to set limit of vertical or horizontal line in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot part of `geom_vline` or `geom_hline`,codes as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10)
plt <- ggplot(data=df)+
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=x[2]))+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=y[2]))
```

I expect to display the left and lower part line as the cross point. 
but there is no argument such as `xlim` or `ylim` in  `geom_vline`

[image]

Comment: `geom_segment` lets you plot lines with x and y limits

Comment: with `geom_segment` you can set upper limits to`Inf` to ensure they extend to edge of plot

Comment: get it! Thx very much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `geom_line`.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10)
plt <- ggplot(data=df)+
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_line(data = data.frame(x = c(2, Inf), y = c(2, 2)), aes(x = x , y = y)) +
  geom_line(data = data.frame(x = c(2, 2), y = c(2, Inf)), aes(x = x, y = y))
```

Or `geom_segment`. They resulted in the same plot.

```
plt <- ggplot(data=df)+
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2 , y = 2, xend = Inf, yend = 2)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2 , y = 2, xend = 2, yend = Inf))
```

[image]