# In ggplot2, stop geom_vline from going below the x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code makes this plot [image: histogram]

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg))  +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(x = mpg ))) +
  geom_histogram()
```

I want the vertical line to show the average of the variable. How do I stop the vline from going below the x-axis? I've tried setting `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, NA))` and it didn't work.

**Edit:** The code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886533/are-there-easy-way-to-set-limit-of-vertical-or-horizontal-line-in-ggplot) solves the problem using `geom_segment` and `geom_line`. These require more arguments however so I'm keeping this up in the hopes that there's a solution with `geom_vline`.

Comment: Either remove the padding `scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.05))` or use `annotate("segment", ....)` to make a line that runs from 0 to Inf.

Comment: See e.g. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886533/are-there-easy-way-to-set-limit-of-vertical-or-horizontal-line-in-ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886533/are-there-easy-way-to-set-limit-of-vertical-or-horizontal-line-in-ggplot) for an example using `geom_segment` as suggested by Jon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there easy way to set limit of vertical or horizontal line in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886533/are-there-easy-way-to-set-limit-of-vertical-or-horizontal-line-in-ggplot)

Comment: Thanks all! Just added a note about this. I'm hoping to stick with `geom_vline` but it's great to know about the `geom_segment` and `geom_line` approaches.